# Use a global CloudStorageAccount variable

Tags: c#, .net, azure, global-variables

I have a question regarding the CloudStorageAccount variable. I've been using and declaring it frequently in my code and i was wondering if it could result into conflict to declare it as a global variable, and use it in every function. I'll demonstrate my question with a simple example.

```
public class AzureQueueSvc : IQueueSvc
{
    DoclQueue _queue;

    public AzureQueueSvc(DoclQueue queue)
    {
        _queue = queue;
        _queue.Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
    }

    public CloudQueue GetQueue { get; }

    public void CreateQueue()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_queue.Connectionstring);
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(_queue.Name);
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public bool QueueExists()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_queue.Connectionstring);
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(_queue.Name);

        if (queue.Exists())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void SendMessage(DoclMessage message)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_queue.Connectionstring);
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(_queue.Name);
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();

        CloudQueueMessage msg = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format(message.ToString()));
        queue.AddMessage(msg);

    }
}
```

As you can see i have to declare the CloudStorageAccount, CloudQueueClient & CloudQueue 3 times. Would it result into conflict to declare them as global variable, and share their usage in my methods?

Comment: In you particular example, as long as you're using the same storage account and queue name I think you can declare them as global variable. HTH.

Comment: Are you sure it won't cause thread problems when the class gets used by multiple users?

Comment: As long as these are local to the class i.e. global at class level instead of application level (especially `CloudQueue`) and not marked as static, I think you should be fine.